# Error handling with time conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I'm using the following to handle what I perceive to be the multitude of time formats a user can type into a data entry form (where the codebase is extremely limited in field validation or forcing time formats). Essentially, it's a free-text field and we "hope" that folks read the mouse-over tip that states something like "Please enter time like 8:00 AM". Data is then fired to SQL. Having been around long enough, I know folks will read that and enter time in every format other than "8:00 AM". To deal with that, and the lack of ability to force the front-end to validate the format, I've implemented the following in a SQL trigger that handles the various time formats when the results from the front-end post to the SQL table:

```
TIME_START = CASE
            --Time Format like 0800 or 1030 or 2230
            WHEN p.TIME_START LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' THEN CONVERT(time, LEFT(p.TIME_START,2) + ':' + RIGHT(p.TIME_START,2) + ':00', 108)
            --Time Format like 800 or 930
            WHEN p.TIME_START LIKE '[0-9][0-9][0-9]' THEN CONVERT(time, '0' + LEFT(p.TIME_START,1) + ':' + RIGHT(p.TIME_START,2) + ':00', 108)
            --Time Format like 08:30 or 22:30
            WHEN p.TIME_START LIKE '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' OR p.TIME_START LIKE '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' THEN CONVERT(time, p.TIME_START, 109)
            --Time Format like 8:30 or 9:35
            WHEN p.TIME_START LIKE '[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' OR p.TIME_START LIKE '[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' THEN CONVERT(time, p.TIME_START, 108)
            -- Time Format like 08:30 AM or 12:30 PM
            WHEN p.TIME_START LIKE '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] AM' OR p.TIME_START LIKE '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] PM' THEN                 CONVERT(time, p.TIME_START, 0)
            --Time Format like 8:30 AM or 7:45 PM
            WHEN p.TIME_START LIKE '[0-9]:[0-9][0-9] AM' OR p.TIME_START LIKE '[0-9]:[0-9][0-9] PM' THEN CONVERT(time, p.TIME_START, 0)
            --Time Format like 08:30:00 AM or 21:45:00 PM
            WHEN p.TIME_START LIKE '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] AM' OR p.TIME_START LIKE '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] PM' THEN CONVERT(time, p.TIME_START, 0)
            --Time Format like 8:30:00 AM or 7:45:00 PM
            WHEN p.TIME_START LIKE '[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] AM' OR p.TIME_START LIKE '[0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9] PM' THEN CONVERT(time, p.TIME_START, 0)
            END
```

Which works great. If I get "0800" or "8:00 AM" or "08:00 AM" and so forth, SQL will always post "08:00:00.0000000" (we want and need the time(n)format to do some math on time later).

The problem is, I can't seem to wrap my head around some error handling that will post a default, dummy value to the TIME_START if someone enters a time that doesn't match one of these formats, such as "2930" or "19:00 AM", or even "6 O'Clock" or "Six O'Clock At Night". Currently, SQL just throws an error when that happens. As stated previously, putting that error handling in the front-end code is not an option (the API only supports DATETIME, was never really intended to support a time-only field in the "Form Builder", you're dying to know, this is the Esri "Web Application Builder"). I'd just like to get a dummy value when a time is out of format such as "00:00:00.00000", which would THEN allow us to look at all the rows with "00:00:00.00000" and then look back at the data entry logs and try to translate what they intended to enter, or follow up with the user and ask what time they really meant, a situation I expect to happen 5% of the time. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: you can save yourself a lot of pain by providing users appropriate tool to entre time values on application layer, for instance in C# application you can use [`TimePicker`](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/170684/Time-Picker) which will give users a uniform way of selecting time values, less headache for you, more sleek and convenient for frondend users too.

Comment: Unfortunately we're limited to what the cloud-provider gives us to use as a data-entry form, and can not modify it. "...putting that error handling in the front-end code is not an option"

Answer (score 0):

Ah, server-side user entry validation… I feel your pain. :)

For your error case, all you would need to do is specify `ELSE` as part of your `CASE` statement. However, I saw some improvement that could have been made in your `LIKE` statements. For example, the first case would match `'9999'` and `'2468'`, both invalid times.

I'm a little tired and haven't been able to test this for all cases, but the following should hopefully work:

```
/*
-- This section provided to give the query context
CREATE TABLE ##TimeTable (
  TIME_START VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL
  );


INSERT INTO ##TimeTable (TIME_START) VALUES('19:00 AM');
INSERT INTO ##TimeTable (TIME_START) VALUES('2930');
INSERT INTO ##TimeTable (TIME_START) VALUES('1930');
*/

SELECT
        CASE
            --Time Format like 0800 or 1030 or 2230
            WHEN p.TIME_START LIKE '[0-1][0-9][0-5][0-9]' 
                OR p.TIME_START LIKE '2[0-3][0-5][0-9]' 
                THEN CONVERT(time, LEFT(p.TIME_START,2) + ':' + RIGHT(p.TIME_START,2) + ':00', 108)
            --Time Format like 800 or 930
            WHEN p.TIME_START LIKE '[0-9][0-5][0-9]' THEN CONVERT(time, '0' + LEFT(p.TIME_START,1) + ':' + RIGHT(p.TIME_START,2) + ':00', 108)
            --Time Format like 08:30 or 22:30
            WHEN p.TIME_START LIKE '[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]' 
                OR p.TIME_START LIKE '2[0-3]:[0-5][0-9]' 
                THEN CONVERT(time, p.TIME_START, 109)
            --Time Format like 8:30 or 9:35
            WHEN p.TIME_START LIKE '[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]' 
                OR p.TIME_START LIKE '[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]' 
                THEN CONVERT(time, p.TIME_START, 108)
            -- Time Format like 08:30 AM or 12:30 PM
            WHEN p.TIME_START LIKE '0[0-9]:[5-9][0-9] [AP]M' 
                OR p.TIME_START LIKE '1[0-2]:[5-9][0-9] [AP]M' 
                THEN CONVERT(time, p.TIME_START, 0)
            --Time Format like 8:30 AM or 7:45 PM
            WHEN p.TIME_START LIKE '[0-9]:[0-5][0-9] [AP]M' 
                THEN CONVERT(time, p.TIME_START, 0)
            --Time Format like 08:30:00 or 21:45:00
            WHEN p.TIME_START LIKE '[0-1][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]' 
                OR p.TIME_START LIKE '2[0-3]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]' 
                THEN CONVERT(time, p.TIME_START, 0)
            --Time Format like 08:30:00 AM or 09:45:00 PM
            WHEN p.TIME_START LIKE '0[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] [AP]M' 
                OR p.TIME_START LIKE '1[0-2]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] [AP]M' 
                THEN CONVERT(time, p.TIME_START, 0)
            --Time Format like 8:30:00 AM or 7:45:00 PM
            WHEN p.TIME_START LIKE '[0-9]:[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9] [AP]M' 
                THEN CONVERT(time, p.TIME_START, 0)
            ELSE CAST('06:00' AS TIME)
        END
FROM ##TimeTable AS p;
```